# c++ What does this argument mean in the command line? | grep MATCH >zoutmatchess

Tags: c++, linux, unix, parameters, arguments

So I have three arguments going into the execution of my program from the command line that appear like this:

```
../../xinputa.txt ../../xinputb.txt | grep MATCH > aoutmatches
```

(This command was given to me as the arguments to use).

And in the main of my program, I have:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  double timenew = 0.0;
  string data_filename = "";
  string pattern_filename = "";
  string timestring = "";
  string outFileName = "";
  ofstream cout;

  Scanner in_scanner;

  SMatch stringmatch;

  CheckArgs(3, argc, argv, "datafilename patternfilename outfilename");
  data_filename = static_cast<string>(argv[1]);
  pattern_filename = static_cast<string>(argv[2]);
  outFileName = static_cast<string>(argv[3]);

  FileOpen(cout, outFileName);


  cout << kTag << "Beginning execution\n";
```

I have a lot of lines that look like the one directly above ^

I finish my main.cc with:

```
FileClose(cout);
```

This info is just to give you a little but of context. I just want to know if

these arguments fit what I'm asking for and what this argument means exactly:

```
| grep MATCH >zoutmatchess
```

Comment: `cout` is a very bad name for a file stream. It is extremely easy to confuse with `std::cout`, the standard output stream.

Comment: `| grep MATCH >zoutmatchess ` is a pipe to a command named `grep`. `>` appends the output of grep to the stated filename.

Answer (score 1):

> ../../xinputa.txt ../../xinputb.txt | grep MATCH > aoutmatches

As it stands, your program has these command line arguments:

- `argv[0]` is your program name
- `argv[1]` points to `../../xinputa.txt`
- `argv[2]` points to `../../xinputb.txt`

The part `| grep MATCH > aoutmatches` is not command line argument per se. It's piping mechanism to direct the program output to the input of `grep` and redirect again the result of that grepping to a file name `aoutmatches`

Comment: Okay, awesome. Still getting blank output files though! I'm not sure what I'm missing if lines like `cout << kTag << "Beginning execution\n"; ` are supposed to pipe

Comment: `cout << kTag << "Beginning execution\n"` is printed to stdout and piped to `grep` - the blank output files means you did not have any `MATCH` in stdout for `grep` to search for

Answer (score 1):

`| grep MATCH >zoutmatchess` is not part of the argument list given to your program, assuming it is called like this:

```
./myProgram ../../xinputa.txt ../../xinputb.txt | grep MATCH > aoutmatches
```

`|` is a pipe which indicates that the output to stdout (standard output, aka `std::cout`) from the preceding command should be redirected to the stdin (standard input, aka `std::cin`) of the following command.

`>` is also a redirect of stdout of the preceding command, but this time to a file specified following the token.

Therefore what your line does is the following:

Start `myProgram` with two arguments `../../xinputa.txt` and `../../xinputb.txt`. Also start `grep` with one argument `MATCH` and then pass the output from `myProgram` as input to `grep` and finally write the output of `grep` to the file `aoutmatches`.

`grep` is a command which filters lines contatining a certain string (`MATCH`).

Therefore you are expected to only take the first two arguments from `argv` (three including the index-zero one, which is the program name) and write the result not to a file, but `std::cout`.

Comment: Wow. Literally so helpful. That is how the program is being called. That would also explain why there were so many lines of code that containing cout. But if I remove the ofstream and outputfile name stuff from the code above, I'm still not getting any output. My two documents are blank that produce after execution. There are many lines that are formatted as follows:

Comment: 'cout << kTag << "Beginning execution\n";

  cout << kTag << "datafile  '" << data_filename << "'\n";'

Comment: Am I missing something? This format seems to fit your description of what the command line is actually asking for. Still nothing...

Comment: Should I change 'kTag' to MATCH?

Comment: After reading over your answer more closely, I realized that I need to include MATCH in every line of text I want piped into my out file. THANK YOU AGAIN

Comment: @JulesMena So are all your problems solved now? Of course there had to be a reason why the ouput is filtered with `grep` first, but I couldn't know what it is. You can just leave out the `| grep MATCH` part to test the raw output of your program.